# Selecionar uma opção no menu drop down Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Tenho um menu que apresenta várias opções, quero selecionar somente a que está ativa. Quando dou 'variável'.find_element_by_id('key') o Selenium me retorna TODAS as opções. A opção ativa tem um marcador "selected", como aponto para está marcação no selenium?

variavel = nanana.find_element_by_id('key')

```
<tr>
            <td class="label"><label for="key"><em>*</em>Key:</label></td>
            <td>
                <select name="key" id="key"><option value="72-N-PR-2">ADEMAR&nbsp;</option>
                    
                        <option value="32-N-PR-2" selected="selected">TEIXEIRA&nbsp;</option>
                    
                        <option value="14-N-PR-2">ANA&nbsp;</option>
                    
                        <option value="45-N-PR-2">RITA&nbsp;</option>
                    
                        <option value="47-N-PR-2">ANDRE&nbsp;</option>                      
                        
                        <option value="23-N-PR-2">JEANE&nbsp;</option>
                    
                        <option value="45-N-PR-2">JOAO&nbsp;</option>
                    
                        <option value="30-N-PR-2">LUIZ&nbsp;</option>
                                            
                        <option value="15-N-PR-2">VALDYR&nbsp;</option>
                    
                        <option value="4-N-AM-2">VANESSA&nbsp;</option>
                    
                        <option value="05-N-PR-2">GARCIA&nbsp;</option></select>
            </td>                   
        </tr>
```

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "opcao ativa"? vc executou um click? quer selecionar um elemento especifico?

Comment: Quando digo ativa quero dizer "selecionada". De todas as opções constantes do menu, é a que se encontra visível no momento. Não pretendo clicar, e sim capturar o texto para tratamento posterior, pois o texto ativo é o que seleciona a tela ativa. Se eu selecionar outra opção do menu, ele me leva pra outra tela.

Comment: Vc esta usando um script 'from scratch" ou está gerando através da IDE do selenium?

Comment: Estou usando o Selenium com Python, tentando evitar o uso do BeautifulSoup (pra não depender de mais uma biblioteca). O Selenium tem localizado tudo que preciso até agora... testando no Idle do Python mesmo.

Comment: Ok, coloque uma possível resposta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: E ai? a resposta atendeu? :-)

Comment: Obrigado amigo! A única alteração que fiz foi colocar "select.first_selected_option"! Fico mto grato!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seleneium tem uma classe para trabalhar com select->option, tente isso:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('key'))

# selecionando pelo texto visivel
select.select_by_visible_text('TEIXEIRA')

# Selecionando pelo valor
select.select_by_value('30632-N-PR-2')
```